# How to get a UTC timestamp from bootstrap-datepicker?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, timestamp, utc, bootstrap-datepicker

How can I get bootstrap-datepicker to return UTC timestamps rather than timestamps based on the user's timezone?

I'm using version 1.8.0 of [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker)

Here's an example which displays the timestamp returned by bootstrap-datepicker when a date is selected:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="js-date">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span id="timestamp-output"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#js-date').datepicker();
});

$('#js-date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
  $('#timestamp-output').text(ev.date.getTime());
});
```

**Fiddle Example**

[bootstrap-datepicker example](https://jsfiddle.net/sw9j6ne8/3/)

**Output**

When you run the example and select the date 11/29/2018, the timestamp displayed is 1543478400000, which corresponds to:

> GMT: Thursday, November 29, 2018 8:00:00 AM

What I need is for it to instead return the timestamp 1543449600000, which corresponds to:

> GMT: Thursday, November 29, 2018 12:00:00 AM

**Summary**

Is there a configuration option in bootstrap-datepicker for this? Or perhaps some reliable way to convert the returned localized timestamp into a UTC timestamp?

Comment: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/methods.html#getutcdate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/). **Updated** I convert a local to UTC timestamp.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#js-date').datepicker();
});

$('#js-date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
  
  var datetime = new Date(ev.date.getTime());
  // Convert local timestamp to UTC timestamp
  var local = moment(datetime).valueOf();
  var utc = (moment(datetime).add(-(moment().utcOffset()), 'm'));
  utc = moment.parseZone(utc).utc().valueOf();
  
  $('#timestamp-local').text('Local Timestamp is ' + local);
  $('#timestamp-utc').text('UTC Timestamp is ' + utc);
  
  console.log('UTC Offset is ' + moment().utcOffset());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.22.2/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="js-date">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span id="timestamp-local"></span><br/>
    <span id="timestamp-utc"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Per  [this](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html) documentation call:

> getUTCDate()

Also Via Javascript:

> var date = new Date(ev.date.getTime() + (60000 * date.getTimezoneOffset()));

Comment: When I use getUTCDate() instead of getTime() it only outputs 28, which apparently is just the day of the month. I need the UTC timestamp corresponding to the full date